# jquery bind dynamicly created mediaplayer.js play event

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, media-player, playback

I have a mediaplayer.js html5 audio player that is dynamically added to the webpage. I want to be able to act on the play event for this element. The following snippet of code works fine for static/non-dynamic mediaplayer.js elements.

```
$('audio, video').on('play',function(){alert('test');});
```

and so I have adapted it for dynamic elements like so

```
$('body').on('play','audio, video',function(){alert('test');});
```

But it doesn't work with either the dynamic or static elements.

Has anyone encountered this before? of have a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging around I have come up with a solution. Use the success callback of the mediaelementplayer options, not exactly what I wanted but does the same thing.

```
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(
{
    success:function(player)
    {
        player.addEventListener('play',function()
        {
            alert('hello');
        });
    }
});
```